# Evaluating C++ pointer to function expression

Tags: c++, stl

I have a C++ class which contains the following definition:

```
class SomeClass:
    public BaseClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    bool SomeClass::MyFunc( Json::Value& jsonRoot)

    typedef bool(SomeClass::*PFUNC)(Json::Value&);
    std::map<std::string, PFUNC> m_map;
}
```

later on in the c++ code i add values to the map variable using the following line:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass()
{
    m_map["func"] = &SomeClass::MyFunc;
}
```

and for execution within one of SomeClass's methods:

```
std::map<std::string, PFUNC>::iterator itFunction = m_map.find("func");
if (itFunction != m_map.end())
{
    PFUNC pfParse = m_map["func"];
    Json::Value x;
    this->*pfParse(x);
}
```

I end up getting the following compilation error:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

I even tried using the iterator explicitly -  this->*iterator->second(...) but ended up with the same error.

what am i doing wrong?
 thanks

Comment: Please read how to make [good examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Well, yours is kind of good but could be better. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()` has higher precedence than `->*` so `pfParse(x)` is evaluated first. You need to use parenthesis to sequence the evaluation:

```
(this->*pfParse)(x);
```